# Problema com o Sequelize com relacionamento

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize-js

Eu tenho duas tabelas chamadas `type_agricultural_implement` e `agricultural_implement`, na qual o `id` de `type_agricultural_implement` está dentro da tabela `agricultural_implement` como `type_agricultural_implement_id`. Assim formando uma relação 1:M.

## Model - type_agricultural_implement

```js
/* jshint indent: 2 */

module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const type_agricultural_implement = sequelize.define(
    'type_agricultural_implement',
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(5).UNSIGNED.ZEROFILL,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
      },
      description: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(90),
        allowNull: false,
      },
    },
    {
      tableName: 'type_agricultural_implement',
    }
  );
  type_agricultural_implement.associate = (models) => {
    type_agricultural_implement.hasMany(models.agricultural_implement, {
      foreignKey: 'type_agricultural_machine_id',
    })
  }
};
```

### Model - agricultural_implement

```js
/* jshint indent: 2 */

module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const agricultural_implement = sequelize.define('agricultural_implement', {
    agricultural_implement_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      references: {
        model: 'agricultural_machine',
        key: 'agricultural_machine_id'
      }
    },
    type_agricultural_machine_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(5).UNSIGNED.ZEROFILL,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'type_agricultural_machine',
        key: 'id',
      },
    },
  }, {
    tableName: 'agricultural_implement'
  });

  agricultural_implement.associate = (models) => {
    agricultural_implement.belongsTo(models.type_agricultural_machine, { foreignKey: 'type_agricultural_machine_id' });
  };

  return agricultural_implement;
};
```

E ao rodar acontece isto

```
Error: agricultural_implement.belongsTo called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu resolvi o problema, no Model `agricultural_implement` onde tem essa parte

```js
type_agricultural_machine_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(5).UNSIGNED.ZEROFILL,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'type_agricultural_machine',
        key: 'id',
      },
    },
  }, {
    tableName: 'agricultural_implement'
  });

  agricultural_implement.associate = (models) => {
    agricultural_implement.belongsTo(models.type_agricultural_machine, { foreignKey: 'type_agricultural_machine_id' });
  };
```

Eu coloquei nome errados, no `type_agricultural_machine_id` era pra ser `type_agricultural_implement_id`, a `references` a mesma coisa, assoaciação também.